# Can I set a custom resolution in TeamViewer 8? I need 1600x900, but closest I can get is 1600x1200

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, resolution, teamviewer

The description says it all. Can I set a custom resolution in TeamViewer 8? I need 1600x900, but closest I can get is 1600x1200. My computer is a Win8 while the computer I am connecting with is a Win7.

Comment: Doesn't remove-access have some options to deal with resolution mis-matches in different ways?

Comment: good reason could be: i'm running the target(where i get my display form) in a vm so any resolution is supported(at least with Vbox)